# Need to access client-side label value (Angular directive) on postback...getting {{radioModel || 'null'}} every time

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, angularjs

Following the code on [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), I was able to integrate the **Radio & Uncheckable Radio** buttons into my solution. I have 2 radio buttons, both of which can be toggled and then I have an asp:Label to display the output.

I would prefer setting the label's visibility to false in the long run but for now it is visible.

By setting the asp:Label **Text** property to `{{radioModel || 'null'}}` I can see the value of the selected radio button on the client side page and viewing the page's source. Problem is, when I post back to the server, specifically attempting to store the value in a database, I only see the `{{radioModel || 'null'}}` declaration, rather than the value of my selection.

*I'm new to Angular but the idea seemed pretty straight forward. I just need to figure out how to retain the label control value when storing to a database.*

**Here is my asp.net code with the angular declaration within the label.**

```
                                <div ng-controller="EmployeeTypeChoiceRadios">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Employee'">Employee</label>
                                    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Contractor'">Contractor</label>

                                    <!-- Pull Results from this label on form submit -->
                                    <asp:Label ID="EmployeeTypeChoiceLabel" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="{{radioModel || 'null'}}" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

**Here is how I have my JavaScript set up. I think this has more to do with the default radio selection however**

```
   //   New Form - Employee Type Employee/Contractor - Radio Button
   var EmployeeTypeChoiceRadios = function ($scope) {

   $scope.radioModel = 'Employee';

   $scope.checkModel = {
       employee: true,
       contractor: false
   };
 };
```

**Finally, here is how I am collecting the label's data - Really just adding to a stored procedure parameter.**

```
newformsqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empEmpType", EmployeeTypeChoiceLabel.Text); // Employee Type choice
```

**For the record, I've also tried basic HTML inputs (Labels) and to get their values like this..**
`BasicHtmlInputLabel.Value`

I appreciate it in advance.

Comment: [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) is not supported on label elements

Comment: @Ufuk Hacıoğulları I see. So to begin with, I should try a different type of control then. That seems fair. Perhaps I could use a simple textbox and see what happens.

Comment: @Ufuk Hacıoğulları This is working as I intended it. Instead of designating an asp.net control however, I am using a basic html input, assigning it an ID and running it at the server on postback. Thank you! Maybe I should have taken some more time to look at the details of Angular. `<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="EmployeeTypeChoiceInput" value="{{radioModel || 'null'}}">`

Comment: @Ufuk Hacıoğulları Please answer the question with what you said so I may mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) is only supported on the following elements:

- input

  - text
  - checkbox
  - radio
  - number
  - email
  - url
  - date
  - dateTimeLocal
  - time
  - month
  - week
- select
- textarea

Using one of them instead of a label should solve the problem.

Comment: Awesome. I appreciate it. I was able to successfully implement a hidden input field and then assign it a server-side ID to get the field value on post-back.